# Read a line containing (large) N reals to an array in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, io

I've read() down past a header of an input file, and read the value of L on the way.

Now I come to a line of L^2 consecutive reals, which I need to input to the elements of an allocatable array A(L,L).

Trying

```
          character *100 :: buffer
          read (1,10) buffer
10      format(a(L*10))
```

results in

```
Error: Syntax error in FORMAT statement at (1)  
Error: FORMAT label 10 at (1) not defined
```

but I'm not sure how else to deal with a (hugely) variable number of reals.

Trying:

```
    do i=1,L
    do j=i,L
        read (1,"(f10.7)") buffer
        read (buffer,*) A(i,j)
    enddo
    enddo
```

throws:

```
Fortran runtime error: Expected REAL for item 2 in formatted transfer, got CHARACTER
    (f10.7)
```

I can't simply read(1,"(a1000)") as L will eventually end up huge, so what I really need is a way to parse the elements one by one.

Please say there's a way?

Comment: I must admit, I'm having difficulty understanding your question. Are you asking "How to read L real numbers from a line into an allocatable array?" ? (if L is unknown read them into a character variable, then using internal read, count them and read them into an array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have processed the header, perhaps by doing "fancy" things by reading it into a string and parsing the string, why not just directly read the numbers from the file and skip the character "buffer"?

"read (unit, *) A" is called "list-directed IO" -- if you want to know what to search for or look up -- it seems like a good approach to me.  It is very flexible -- you don't have to be concerned with precisely aligning you numbers into columns.  If you just read into the array "A", the elements will be read in Fortran array element order.

In Fortran 2003, you can use "*" as a variable format repeat specifier: read (unit, '( *(F10.7) )' ).  However, not many compilers support this yet.   This easiest thing to do is just to use a huge value, larger than you will ever need -- the read will stop when there are no more items on the list to be read -- the repeat specifier is allowed to exceed the number of items read.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1420862&page=1

Update:

http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs201/NOTES/chap05/format.html
http://rainbow.ldgo.columbia.edu/data/fortranreaddata.html

This goes over unformatted record-length reading. It's been a long time since I've had to mess with fortran I/O. I'm pretty certain there's a flag to either OPEN or READ that specifies that it shouldn't continue onto the next line, but rather keep the file pointer in place so that the next READ can start from there. But I can't remember it off-hand...

Comment: Not really, all of my values are on the same line, so parsing line-by-line doesn't really make sense.
It's certainly better than what I had, though, thanks.

Comment: updated with more info, tho still not a complete answer. have you tried reading into an array, and using a format that represents an array of reals?

Comment: To keep reading from the same line, you can use "advance='no'" on the read statement.   I don't think that I would use this for this problem.

Comment: thanks, i haven't had to tackle this in over 10 years, my fortran mojo has withered. much thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Haha, this seems to work:

`read (1,*) A`
`write (*,*) A`

Seems the standard knows what it's doing, even if I don't.

Comment: That's a very dangerous approach.

Comment: Because you don't know what you're doing. And using that approach, you are likely to wind up in a situation where you will think you are doing something, while the program will actually be doing something completely different. And that can be dangerous.

Comment: I believe that this will read until A is full. If you have the wrong size for A, you will either have an end-of-file error or miss values, but otherwise, I think it is ok. (4 years late, but hey)